# Android Activity Not Found Exception Doesn't Make Sense

Tags: android, android-manifest

Okay well I'm trying to make a Live Wallapper but whenever I click on settings it force closes. Saying the activity is not found which doesn't make any sense because, I have it in the Manifest. This is really starting to bug me as I've been at it for over 2 hours.

Logcat:`08-28 01:06:49.903: INFO/ActivityManager(1089): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=quotesandothers.livewallpaper.quotesandothers/quotesandothers.livewallpaper.quotesandothers (has extras) }
08-28 01:06:49.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15221): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-28 01:06:49.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15221): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
08-28 01:06:49.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15221):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
08-28 01:06:49.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15221):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
08-28 01:06:49.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15221):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
08-28 01:06:49.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15221):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-28 01:06:49.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15221):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-28 01:06:49.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15221):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-28 01:06:49.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15221):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-28 01:06:49.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15221):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-28 01:06:49.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15221):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-28 01:06:49.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15221):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-28 01:06:49.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15221):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-28 01:06:49.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15221):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-28 01:06:49.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15221): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-28 01:06:49.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15221):     at com.android.wallpaper.livepicker.LiveWallpaperPreview.configureLiveWallpaper(LiveWallpaperPreview.java:113)
08-28 01:06:49.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15221):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-28 01:06:49.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15221):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-28 01:06:49.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15221):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
08-28 01:06:49.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15221):     ... 11 more
08-28 01:06:49.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15221): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {quotesandothers.livewallpaper.quotesandothers/quotesandothers.livewallpaper.quotesandothers}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
08-28 01:06:49.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15221):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1404)
08-28 01:06:49.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15221):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
08-28 01:06:49.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15221):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
08-28 01:06:49.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15221):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2923)
08-28 01:06:49.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15221):     ... 15 more`

Manifest:`

```
    </application>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.software.live_wallpaper" />
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Your code starting an Activity. You have to mention this Activity in your AndroidManifest.xml.

like:

```
<activity android:name="your.package.name.ActivityClassName">
</activity>
```

Here is part of interest:

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15221): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {quotesandothers.livewallpaper.quotesandothers/quotesandothers.livewallpaper.quotesandothers}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? 08-28
```